# Blazor Web code after await doesn't execute until the second time

Tags: blazor-webassembly

In Blazor Web, I have a method called from a button that does an HttpClient call to an API and then populates a field (Result) on the form. When I call it the first time, nothing happens. When I call it the second time, the field gets populated. Chrome confirms that the API call is made successfully both times. It looks like the code after the await doesn't execute until the 2nd call. What am I doing wrong?

```
private async void DoAPICall()
{
    VerificationReturnType ReturnData = await Http.GetFromJsonAsync<VerificationReturnType>(APIMethod);
    Result = String.Format("TrustedCookie: {0}\r\nVerificationCookie: {1}\r\nError: {2}\r\n", ReturnData.TrustedCookie, ReturnData.VerificatonCookie, ReturnData.Error);
}
```

Comment: Never use `async void` except for actual event handlers - handlers for things defined with `event` or delegates that don't accept a `Task` return value

Answer (score 0):

Fixed by changing the return type of the DoAPICall from void to Task. Even though the DoAPICall is functionally the event handler for the web form button onclick event and async event handlers usually have to have the void return type, in this (Blazor Web) context, the method must have the Task return type.

Also, (which was my first solution), don't try to call the GetFromJsonAsync method synchronously by appending .Result, like you might when writing a backend C# application. It will compile OK but blow up running in the browser.

Really hope this helps someone else with beginner mistakes - Blazor Web has such potential!

Comment: It's *not* an event handler, even if the name says so. It's a callback with special state updating magic. `async void` is meant *specifically* for old-style .NET events that can't be handled by delegates that return `Task`.